# changing mouse events to touch events

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, touch-event

I'm trying to use [THIS](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/06/apple-like-retina-effect-jquery-css/demo.html)  zoom plugin but its only works using mouse events is there any easy way to convert it to touch events?

cheers

Comment: I assume you want to convert the hover mouse event to a touch-and-hold event? This is probably a bad idea, since there are usually existing touch-and-hold events in the web browser that you'd end up trying to override.

Comment: yeh, it still works with touch but with limited functionality because it dosnt read the hover events it just jumps to the area when you touch it with your finger, from there if you drag your finger it does nothing

Comment: Give the plugin author the benefit of the doubt; he probably already thought through what you want to do and has a good reason for not doing it.